# grails is reformatting my date

Tags: grails, jodatime

I have the following domain for a groovy grails project

```
class Title {

    // Automatic timestamping
    DateTime dateCreated
    DateTime lastUpdated

    String name
    LocalDate startDate
    LocalDate endDate

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false, maxSize: 100
        startDate nullable: true
        endDate nullable: true
        // TODO: Validation check to make sure endDate is after startDate
    }
}
```

the start date uses jodatime's `LocalDate`.

My problem is, when I go to update the `startDate` field, I have to use the following format `mm/dd/yyyy`, but it stores the date in the database as `yyyy-mm-dd`. I want to make my input field, for the start date, accept `yyyy-mm-dd` because that is how it's stored in the database. I get the following error if I try to submit my form using any other format than the slashes

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.joda.time.LocalDate for property startDate; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-01-01" is malformed at "14-01-01"

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Should I just reformat the string?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using **Joda Time** plugin? If yes, you should map your field to

```
static mapping = {
    startDate type: PersistentLocalDate
    endDate type: PersistentLocalDate
}
```

In your model.